# Is there a way to see if your mic is currently active in solo mode?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I've played a game recently where when I got Top5, I was camping and heard a 'click-click-click'.

The guy that was coming up to try and fight me had his mic picking up every keystroke and I could hear him coming via proximity chat.

Now I'm paranoid; does my mic pick up ambient sound when I'm playing?

In squads, you can see your own mic when it's picking up (there's a little speaker icon next to your name) but in solo, that part of the UI is not there.

So is there a way to see if your mic is currently active in solo mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to tell if your mic is broadcasting in Solo.  Really, there is no reason for you to want to talk to anyone in a solo match, so a few things you can do to mitigate the issue are:

- Mute your mic on your system, or if your mic/headset has a button to mute it, use that
- Have push to talk enabled (<kbd>T</kbd> by default) in the game settings.  That way, your voice will only be broadcasted when you push to talk
- Turn your voice output volume down to 0 in the game settings
- Change your voice chat channel to either "None" or "Team Only" in the game settings

Comment: That was a plan B I thought of after publishing this question.

Answer (score 1):

While there may be no active UI feedback to indicate that you are transmitting, there's several simple solutions:

- Switch Voice Chat Mode to push-to-talk (or off is also an option, IIRC). This is especially effective if you just remove your push-to-talk keybinding.
- Toggle voice chat if you aren't sure. Default binding is <kbd>Ctrl + T</kbd>, I believe. You'll get a quick notification on-screen, and this should be explicit.
  [image: Toggle Mute]
- Change voice channels to team-only. ***This is probably the best solution***, since even if you screw everything else up and leave PTT to broadcast constantly, enemies won't hear you. Default binding is <kbd>Ctrl + Y</kbd> I think.
  [image: Mode and channel]
  [image: Keybindings]